# Entity Framework Core One To Many with No Foreign Key on Master Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

We've decided to consolidate all enums into a RefValue table which I at least have no problem conceiving of, but I can't seem to get Entity to play along.

I think it should make sense once you look at the schema, but the gist of it is that a Person object would have 2 fields when it came to enums (eg gender, relationshipStatus, nameSuffix, etc).  One field would store the value (eg "female") and the other would store the id of that RefValue (eg some guid which would be a foreign key to the RefValue table where the value was stored/defined).  That way we wouldn't have to do multiple joins on the RefValue table to find those properties values.

Here's the schema:

```
[Table("Person")]
public class Person : Base
{
    public Guid Id {get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public RefValue GenderRef { get; set; }

    public string RelationshipStatus { get; set; }
    public RefValue RelationshipStatusRef { get; set; }

    public string NameSuffix { get; set; }
    public RefValue NameSuffixRef { get; set; }
}

[Table("RefValue")]
public class RefValue : Base
{
    public Guid Id {get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

In the Person object, I'd really just like the RefValue properties to just be Guids as foreign keys to the RefValue table.  I started steering towards just making them RefValue properties because it seemed like EFC would make things easier if I did it their way with the concept of navigation properties.  The problem though is that it's pretty insistent on having a column on the RefValue table to be the other side of those one-to-many relationships.

I'm fine with adding extra columns on the RefValue table so that is looks more like this:

```
[Table("RefValue")]
public class RefValue : Base
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> Genders { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> RelationshipStatus { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> NameSuffix { get; set; }
}
```

But no matter how I spin my context class's `OnModelCreating()` method, I can't seem to get them to play together.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<RefValue>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Genders)
            .WithOne(p => p.GenderRef)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
        modelBuilder.Entity<RefValue>()
            .HasMany(p => p.RelationshipStatus)
            .WithOne(p => p.RelationshipStatusRef)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
        modelBuilder.Entity<RefValue>()
            .HasMany(p => p.NameSuffix)
            .WithOne(p => p.NameSuffixRef)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
    }
```

I've tried going the inverse way as well, but I usually get the `Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint ... on table ... may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths`

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasOne(p => p.PersonTypeRef)
            .WithMany()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasOne(p => p.RelationshipStatusRef)
            .WithMany()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasOne(p => p.NameSuffixRef)
            .WithMany()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
    }
```

Is there any way to create this kind of one-to-many (or really many-to-one) kind of relationship without the cascading problem or (and especially) entity creating shadow properties on the non-dependent table?

Comment: The way I handle them is I would create a lookup table since such values do not change often. `LuGender(Code, Desc)`. I will fill it up with `FEM, Female` and `MAL, Male` etc. Then in person I will have a property named `Gender` (same as table name except for `Lu`).  I find `Guid`s are not very descriptive.

Comment: I'm unsure what is the actual problem. Collection navigation properties do not add columns to the table. FK columns are at the other side (the one with reference navigation property). In your case, you simply have *multiple* many-to-one relationships between `Person` and  `RefValue`.  The only problem with such relational design is the *multiple cascade paths* (there is no way to tell the database that FKs use different values), hence you cannot use cascading options, e.g. you should configure the relationships with `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)`.

Comment: CodingYoshi, yeah, I like the idea of using a sort of abbreviation for the lookup code instead of a Guid, however for uniformity, all models inherit from a base class which includes a Guid Id and the 4 standard createdDate/by/updatedDate/by, so I just wanted to keep using that system across all tables.

Comment: Ivan Stoev, maybe it's a difference between standard EF and EF Core?  Here's a [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) to where they talk about how EFC creates shadow properties, and specifically in the one-to-many relationships.  I think you are right though that this may be dead-end in regards to the cascading.  I'm thinking it might be worth foregoing the cascade deletes in lieu of managing FK relationships manually as I don't like EF imposing its opinions and subsequently creating tightly coupled dependencies too it ("tightly coupled" maybe too strong)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with EF Core relationships. In fact the multiple cascade path problem / limitation originates from SqlServer database. The collection navigation properties are not mandatory, but the fluent API must reflect exactly their presense (`WithMany(p => p.Collection)`) or absence (`WithMany()`). Then all you need is to use `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)`

Answer (score 2):

Let's take your original entity model:

```
[Table("Person")]
public class Person : Base
{
    public Guid Id {get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public RefValue GenderRef { get; set; }

    public string RelationshipStatus { get; set; }
    public RefValue RelationshipStatusRef { get; set; }

    public string NameSuffix { get; set; }
    public RefValue NameSuffixRef { get; set; }
}

[Table("RefValue")]
public class RefValue : Base
{
    public Guid Id {get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

There is absolutely no problem to configure unidirectional (i.e. with navigation property only at one of the sides) FK relationships using the fluent API. The only thing you need to consider is that because of the *multiple cascade paths* introduced by such model, you can't use delete cascade options, i.e. you should specify `DeleteBehavior.Restrict`.

With that being said, here is the fluent configuration for the above model:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasOne(p => p.GenderRef)
    .WithMany()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasOne(p => p.RelationshipStatusRef)
    .WithMany()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasOne(p => p.NameSuffixRef)
    .WithMany()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

And in case you add collection navigation properties, don't forget to specify them in the corresponding `WithMany` calls, otherwise EF Core will create additional relationships.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, yeah, given the concept and EF Core, this is what I was needing to accomplish it.  Still working with my team on whether we want to deal with the behavior that'll result from this decision, but this is actually for a POC project anyways.  We may decide not to go with it in the end anyways, but regardless, this is exactly what I needed.  Thanks Ivan.

Answer (score 1):

> We've decided to consolidate all enums into a RefValue table

That makes me sad.  How are you going to keep people from having a gender of Single, or a relationship status of Female?  How are you going to populate a drop-down with all the valid values for a particular foreign key?  How are you going to help report writers from joining the tables correctly?

> I can't seem to get them to play together.

That's because what you are attempting is a fundamental violation of relational design. And this is just the first of many difficulties that should make you rethink this design.

Comment: They seem to have some sort of a discriminator (`public string Type`) in the `RefValue` though, so I guess they can distinguish between `Gender`, `RelationshipStatus` etc. "enums".

Comment: Yeah, Ivan is correct about the `Type` field.  It is true that you could ignore that field when accessing the property and therefore use an inappropriate value in the person object, however no more than that's possible in any other field.  After GETting the person object, if you were to access the edit page, you would initially do a GET to get all relevant `RefValues` for any potential dropdowns.